# should I use FXG or bitmap images to create my custom skins?

Tags: apache-flex, skin

I need to create a lot of custom Flex 4 skins, in most of the examples I found on the web people use FXG in order to create the skins but if a lot of the icons I use are not resizeable should I still use FXG or better use just plain old bitmap images (jpg. png)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For images that don't need to be scaled, just use a **.png** image.

Use FXG when you need to scale or dynamically redraw an image/shape etc.

Remember, you can always replace a fixed image with FXG later on if you need those features, so don't worry about creating FXG assets that aren't necessary up-front.